# Edit and continue doesn't work correctly in VS2015+SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In my experience in Visual Studio 2015 Edit and Continue with C# doesn't work correctly anymore. I tried again with service pack 1, but it still  doesn't work correctly.

E.g. I hit a breakpoint, then I comment out a line or add a comment.
When I want to continue debugging, the IDE tells me it doesn't compile and only gives the options: Stop or Edit.
After Edit the Window "Error List"  doesn't show any compile errors, of course not, e.g. I just added a comment.

Note: the target platfrom is X86 on a 64bit machine.
Language C#.
It is a single thread.
Intellitrace is disabled.
The code is not optimized.
No Linq expressions involved.
It works with no problems in VS2013.
Am I doing something wrong or is this just a worsening?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language or project type you are using. If you are using C++, here is a good blog post on this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/22/c-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx

BTW IntelliTrace does not affect Edit and Continue with its default settings. The only IntelliTrace option that affects EnC is asking it to collect every single method call in the application. Here is a blog post with more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/29/intellitrace-method-call-information-and-edit-and-continue.aspx

Comment: I use C# as language and do not use "Intelli"Trace. Edit and Continue has become almost completely useless.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying this with an existing project and it's not working for you. Have you tried a brand new console application? Hopefully that works and then we can try to figure out what's so special about your existing project.

Comment: BTW you can also contact me directly at angelos.petropoulos@Microsoft.com if that helps. We will make sure we update the answer here once we figure it out.